# Flextable table links not linking to my tables

Tags: r-markdown, docx, flextable

I have generated tables in docx using Rmarkdown (Output: word_document), with captions and links to the tables. For some reason clicking on the links takes me to the top of my word file and not to the relevant table.
Here is some example code: #*first time having an rmarkdown related issue, please bare with me*

```
library(officer)
library(flextable)
library(knitr)
library(magrittr)

# set chunks defaults
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE)

#create example df
df1 <- data.frame(col1=c("a","b","c"),
        col2=c("1","2","3"))
df2 <- data.frame(col1=c("d","e","f"),
                  col2=c("4","5","6"))
```

(Link to table 2) <--- this link should take me to flextable 2, but it doesn't.

```
#create flextable 1
ft1 <- flextable(df1)
ft1 <- set_caption(ft1, "Caption 1.",
                   style = "Table Caption", 
                   autonum = run_autonum(seq_id = "tab",bkm="tab1"))

ft1
```

(Link to Table 1) <---- This link should take me to table 1, but it doesn't.
*I set these links in this order to hopefully make the problem clearer.*

```
#links created using format [(Link)](#tab:tab2)

#second flextable
ft2 <- flextable(df2)
ft2 <- set_caption(ft2, "Caption 2.",
                   style = "Table Caption",
                   autonum = run_autonum(seq_id = "tab",bkm="tab2"))

ft2
```

if this is possible using flextable, I am probably making a small mistake somewhere, but can't spot it. *So far this is the only function I found that renders docx table output using Rmarkdown*

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that might run into this problem.

Using the example @manro made above, I got it to work by editing the YAML.

```
title: "Untitled"
author: "Your Name"
date: "December 16, 2021"
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: template.docx
```

```
library(flextable)
library(officedown)
library(officer)

#create example df
df1 <- data.frame(col1=c("a","b","c"),
        col2=c("1","2","3"))
df2 <- data.frame(col1=c("d","e","f"),
                  col2=c("4","5","6"))
```

```
ft1 <- flextable(df1)
set_caption(ft1, "I love R language")
```

\newpage

```
ft2 <- flextable(df2)
set_caption(ft2, "I hope, it loves me too")
```

\newpage

And by removing "tab:" from `[(Link)](#tab:tab2)` from the link examples below.

`[(Click, here is the first table)](#tab:Table1)`

`[(Here is the second)](#tab:Table2)`

leaving me with.

`[(Click, here is the first table)](#Table1)`

`[(Here is the second)](#Table2)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I made this example for you:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Your Name"
date: "December 16, 2021"
output:
  bookdown::word_document2: default
---

```{r setup}
library(flextable)

#create example df
df1 <- data.frame(col1=c("a","b","c"),
        col2=c("1","2","3"))
df2 <- data.frame(col1=c("d","e","f"),
                  col2=c("4","5","6"))
```     

```{r Table1}
ft1 <- flextable(df1)
set_caption(ft1, "I love R language")
```    
\newpage

```{r Table2}
ft2 <- flextable(df2)
set_caption(ft2, "I hope, it loves me too")
```       
\newpage

[(Click, here is the first table)](#tab:Table1)
   
[(Here is the second)](#tab:Table2)
````

Good luck and the big success in the process of R learning to you;)

---

**An addition:**

````
```{r Table3, tab.cap = "An another table"}
flextable(df2)
```

\newpage

Ok, here is a third table [(Here is the third)](#tab:Table3).
````

Comment: This does not solve the problem but it does highlight the issue nicely (I'm assuming that's what you were going for). Thank you.

Comment: @Pepper It works right. ```Knit with parameters -> knit to word_document2```

Comment: I double checked the code and ran it again, with the right output option. Still does not work on my end. I think it might be an issue with the office word settings on my system. Not the desired result of the code, but right clicking the links and manually targeting them to the right tables works.

Comment: @Pepper Hm, I don't know. But this is a working example. Try this addition.